# Angular materialize font not found

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli, materialize

I'm trying to integrate materialize but when i try add

```
"./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
```

and

```
"./node_modules/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss",
```

to webpack.config.json

I get this error on build (I get multiple) :

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./~/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff2' in 'C:\Users\Administrateur\Documents\dev\git\front-ptc-angular\node_modules\materialize-css\sass'
 @ ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./~/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss 6:77358-77402
 @ ./~/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss
 @ multi ./~/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss ./src/assets/scss/main.scss
```

Any idea ?

EDIT :

I added angular2-materialize and materialize-css by npm

then added the two lines to my webpack config

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize and running through the install guide at the bottom?

Comment: I got it via NPM, this is not the first project I do with materialize, but I never had this kind of issue :/

Answer (score 0):

I used **materialize** with **bower** and it gave me the same problem, I resolved it by copying the folder / fonts / roboto to the level of where the css and js folders of materialize are.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the angular2-materialize you have to check if you're using the materialize version 0.100.2 because that version is the only compatible